# mysqlにログインしたいがアクセス権限で拒否されます。

Tags: mysql

mysqlをバージョンアップさせて、テストでログインしようとしたのですが、
アクセス拒否のエラーとなり、ログインすることが出来ませんでした。

作業は以下の記事を参考に行いました。

[AWS EC2 AmazonLinux2 MySQL rootユーザの初期パスワードの確認方法](https://qiita.com/miriwo/items/457d6dbf02864f3bf296)

`sudo less /var/log/mysqld.log` を実行し、書かれているパスワードをログイン時に入力したのですが、アクセス権限で拒否されログインできませんでした。

```
ec2-user:~/environment/myapp $ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

そこでmysqlのプロセスと権限を確認してみました。

```
ec2-user:~/environment $ ls -la /usr/sbin/mysqld
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 64627896 Mar 16 19:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld
```

```
ec2-user:~/environment/myapp $ ps -ef | grep mysql
mysql    13078     1  0 03:58 ?        00:00:03 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root     13398 10068  0 03:58 pts/5    00:00:00 sudo less /var/log/mysqld.log
root     13400 13398  0 03:58 pts/5    00:00:00 less /var/log/mysqld.log
ec2-user 18299 12161  0 04:10 pts/3    00:00:00 grep --color=auto mysql
```

恐らくちゃんと動いているように見えました。
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)で検索を行い、色々と調べては試してみているのですが、解決には至っていません。
まずは原因をしっかりと知りたいと思っております。

mysqlバージョン：mysql  Ver 8.0.33 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

mysqlのインストールは[AWS EC2 AmazonLinux2 MySQLをインストールする](https://qiita.com/miriwo/items/eb09c065ee9bb7e8fe06)を参考にインストールを実施しました。

開発ツール：Cloud9
OS：Windows11

Comment: バージョンアップ前にはログイン出来ていたのでしょうか？また、念のため OS の種類やバージョンについての情報も記載してみてください。

Comment: MySQL をインストールした後バージョンアップし、そしてログインを試みているということで合っていますか？　インストール直後に root user のパスワードを最初のテンポラリな設定から書き換えませんでしたか。

Comment: OSの種類とバージョンは、追って質問に記載させて頂きます。また、インストール後のroot userのパスワードですが、インストール直後に一番最初に記載したサイトの手順に従い、sudo less /var/log/mysqld.logで初期のパスワードを調べてそこに書かれているパスワードを使い、ログインを試みようとした際に、ログインが出来ませんでした。

Comment: OSの種類を記載させて頂きました。ちなみに使用している環境はCloud9です。

Comment: つまり「mysqlをバージョンアップさせて」というのは後で行おうとしたことで、今はまだバージョンアップもしていないということですね。あくまでインストール直後の話だと理解しました。

Comment: この状況だと一番ありえそうなのはパスワードの打ち間違いです。記号も含め正しいパスワードを入力できているか、いま一度確認してみてください。ログインする際にはパスワードとして入力した文字列が表示されないので気付きにくいところではあります。

Comment: 打ち間違えていました。パスワードの>fhwd&gJi6=Kの>の箇所が抜けていました。ログイン出来たらrootのパスワードを変更できますか？

Comment: 解決して良かったです。同じことを回答として投稿しておきました: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/95666/19110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yum install` からインストールした直後に localhost のクライアントから localhost の MySQL サーバーへログインできないという今回の状況だと、一番ありえそうなのはパスワードの打ち間違いです。記号も含め正しいパスワードを入力できているか、いま一度確認してみてください。ログインする際にはパスワードとして入力した文字列が表示されないので気付きにくいところではあります。

ログインできたら alter user で新しいパスワードを設定しておきましょう。

MySQL 公式ドキュメントの Postinstallation Setup についても URL を載せておきます: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-installation-excerpt/8.0/en/postinstallation.html。パスワードの変更については Securing the Initial MySQL Account に載っています。